# Flink setup: put web UI under path

Tags: load-balancing, apache-flink

I would like to run multiple clusters, with the web UI under the same domain. For example, I would like one cluster's UI to be reachable with `example.com/clusterA`, and the second cluster under `example.com/clusterB`. How can I do this?

I saw the `web.address` parameter, but there's no examples with valid configuration and so far I just keep on getting `java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException`s from Netty.

I also tried to configure the router to just send any requests to `example.com/clusterA` to the jobmanager's `/`, but then the page breaks since all scripts still try to load from `example.com`. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I didn't quite get what you mean with "running multiple clusters with the same web ui". As far as I know each cluster has it's own web ui and doesn't know anything about the other clusters

Comment: I don't want multiple clusters under the same UI, but I would like two different clusters with two different UIs available under the same domain. From what I found so far, the UI must be mounted under `/`. I'd like to mount it under `/clusterA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see that is not possible by just changing the flink configuration. The property `web.address` just defines the (IP)-address the web ui should be bound to. There is nothing which defines a base path. Maybe some load-balancer magic can do the trick but that is beyond Flink.